# how does a program recognize the computer?

Tags: reinstall

a pretty fundamental question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet..

Basically, by what means does software recognize hardware? Good example of this are trial programs.
Once the trial ends, it tells you to pay. For some, it is enough to just uninstall and re-install back on. But for most, this approach does not work.

How does the program recognize the computer when basically all traces of the previous installation are deleted? (yes, I did remove the program's registry).

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you got rid of all traces?

Comment: Registry is not the only place where traces can be left. Other options could be some hidden directories in your user folder or even communicating with cloud services storing some identifying information about your hardware.

Comment: [How do trial programs know they have been on your computer before?](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/how-do-trial-programs-know-they-have-been-on-your-computer-before.83511/)

Comment: Depends on the program;  what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound I appeared like (as he said in his question) he was trying to learn how a program recognizes the computer.  He might be trying to use the method to protect property he's writing.  Of course, the question and answer might prove valuable to others who perform the search and are looking for ways to provide secured distributions of trial installations of their property.

Comment: I like actual problems. "how does drm work" is a vague question.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the answers. Precisely as L.D.James said, I was curious about the principles behind this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the software often takes a lot of time to find ways to identify if the program has already been installed and when.  Also, it usually places traces in various locations on the system.

If you learn the technique for one program, that technique might not work for a different one.  Also some developers don't go as far as others.

Some might ask you to register the program before you use it.  If that were the case, it would be obvious that upon registration it's logging information concerning you and the installed application.  Some places information in the register and checks that for validation.  Some might use that as the only check.  If that were the case, removing the register entry would start the count back to zero, which works for some programs.

Some programs use the registry plus some other secret location on the computer, where the user might not think to look.

For many programs it might be more costly to spend many hours trying to figure out the technique use for that program.  If you consider an hourly value of your time or what you might pay an expert to figure it out for you, it might be much less expensive to just pay the fee to officially register the program.

If a developer wrote something in some 5 random location and the public found the five, on their next version they might add 10 random locations and try to make those even harder to find.

By the way, it's very clear that any program I've checked in the past actually uses the computer itself, because if you placed a clean drive and performed a clean installation, the program would start over as a fresh install.

So if someone took a program and figured that one out, whatever you found would probably only work for that one program.  There wouldn't be a guarantee that it would even work for the next version or security update of that particular program you were able to figure out.

Comment: We had this control system software in our office - which requires the registration of MAC ID during installation. Once a license is used up per MAC ID - you need to purchase a new one for the next PC. If your network (NIC) card fails - then it might be a problem as you would want to use the software on the same PC but pay again if you want to re-install the software after  a clean wipe.  In our industry, clean wipe is not an option as the process plant is being controlled by this computer